# NoReverseMatch not matching key argument

Tags: django, django-views

I have a response error that is driving me crazy, I tried everything but no way to find why am I getting that error :

```
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found.
1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']
```

that is my views:

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'

class LinkTeam(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'link_project.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        #team2 = Team.objects.all().filter(team_hr_admin = self.request.user)
        queryset = Team.objects.filter(team_hr_admin=self.request.user)
        return queryset

def TeamSelect(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            data = select_form.cleaned_data['team_choice']
            obj2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin=request.user)
            obj3 = obj2.latest('id')
            if obj3.team_id == None:
                obj3.team_id = data
                obj3.save()
                obj4 = obj3.team_id
                obj5 = obj4.members.all()

                for i in obj5:
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': i.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = i.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'test')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk':obj3.id}))
            else:
                print('this project has already a team')
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')

    else:
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })

class HRIndex(generic.ListView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "HR_index.html"
    model = Project

class CandidateIndex(TemplateView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "candidate_index.html"

class EmployeeIndex(TemplateView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "employee_index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        surveys = Survey.objects.filter(is_published=True)
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            surveys = surveys.filter(need_logged_user=False)
        context['surveys'] = surveys
        return context

class ProjectCreate(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.project_hr_admin = self.request.user
        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class ProjectDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,generic.DetailView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(Project,id=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
            context['team_name'] = team_name
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return context

class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], members__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        team_list = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        team_list_pop = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all().exclude(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])

        context={
            'employee_name' : employee_name,
            'team_list' : team_list,
            'team_list_pop' : team_list_pop
        }
        return context

class TeamCreate(CreateView):

    model = Team
    fields = ['team_name']
    template_name = 'team_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        valid = super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.team_hr_admin = self.request.user
        obj = form.save()
        #SELECT * FROM project WHERE user = 'current_user' AND team_id = NULL
        obj2 = Project.objects.get(project_hr_admin=self.request.user, team_id=None)
        obj2.team_id = obj
        obj2.save()
        return valid
        return super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        project = Project.objects.get(team_id=None, project_hr_admin=self.request.user)
        return project.get_absolute_url()
```

URL:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from website import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hr_index/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='hr_index'),
    url(r'^candidate_index/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(),name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^employee_index/$', views.EmployeeIndex.as_view(),name='employee_index'),
    url(r'^addproject/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='add_project'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/addteam/$', views.TeamCreate.as_view(), name='add_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam/$', views.LinkTeam.as_view(), name='link_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$', views.TeamSelect, name='team_select'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data2/$',views.TeamChartData.as_view(), name='TeamChartData'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$',views.EmployeeChartData.as_view(), name='EmployeeChartData'),
    #url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$', views.ChartData.as_view(), name='chartdata'),

]
```

the keyword argument say that pk1 is empty when it should not since I am in the page http://127.0.0.1:8000/website/project/2/

My template look like...................................

```
{% load static %}
<div class="invite-team">
  <div class="jumbotron greenback">
    <div class="jumbo-text">
      <h7>Your project has been created, It is time to link a team or create a new for your project</h3>
    </div>
      <div class="jumbo-button">
        <a href="{% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
        <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>   Create a new team</a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

edit:
the error appeared after I added :

```
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'project_details.html'


class TeamChartData(APIView):
    queryset = MyUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyUserSerializer, #ProjectSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    http_method_names = ['get',]
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'project_details.html'


    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_class


    def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):
        chunk_team = get_team_info_score(self)
        motiv_team = get_team_motivation_score(self)
        action_team = get_team_action_score(self)
        behav_team = get_behaviour_action_score(self)
        team_complete = get_team_complete_data(self)
        cohesiveness_score = get_team_cohesivenss_score(self)
        info_dist = get_question_similarities(self)[0]
        motiv_dist = get_question_similarities(self)[1]
        action_dist = get_question_similarities(self)[2]
        behav_dist = get_question_similarities(self)[3]
data = {
            "team_info_score":chunk_team,
            "team_motiv_score":motiv_team,
            "team_action_score":action_team,
            "team_behaviour_score":behav_team,
            "team_complete":team_complete,
            "cohesiveness_score":cohesiveness_score[0],
            "users":cohesiveness_score[1],
            "user_dist":cohesiveness_score[2],
            "info_dist":info_dist,
            "motiv_dist": motiv_dist,
            "action_dist":action_dist,
            "behav_dist":behav_dist,
            "complete_label":complete_label,

            "info_label":processing_information_label,
            "motivation_label": motivation_label,
            "action_label":action_label,
            "behav_label":other_data_label,

        }
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code that is failing. You are either calling `reverse(team_select, ...)` in a view or model method, or `{% url 'team_select' ... %}` in the template.

Comment: in my template I have 'website:add_team' pk1=project.id %}, I edited my post, but my url should be ok no ?

Comment: You have `{% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %}` and the error says `with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}'`, which suggests that `project` isn't set in your template context. You're using a `DetailView` with `model=Project`, so I don't know why that's happening.

Comment: When you use the login required mixin it should come before the view, e.g. `class EmployeeDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):`. I don't know whether that is what's causing the problem here.

Comment: Me neither and it is drinving me crazy ;) It  appeared after I added  renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer] template_name = 'project_details.html' look at my edited post

Comment: You still haven't fixed the `LoginRequiredMixin` in your code. From your URL patterns, `/website/project/2/` should be handled by `ProjectDetailView`, so I don't see why your `TeamChartData` view would have any effect.

Comment: I changed it in my code, not in the post but I am still getting the error ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162552/discussion-between-ben2pop-and-alasdair).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url reverse looks fine. The problem is that you don't set `project` to your context in `ProjectDetailView`:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    try:
        project = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1'])
        team_name = project.team_id.members.all()
        context['team_name'] = team_name
        context['project'] = project
    except AttributeError:
        pass
    return context
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding namesspace ? right html look like : <div class="jumbo-button">
        <a href="{% url 'website:team_select' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-secondary" role="button"><span class="fa fa-link"></span>   Link an existing team</a>
        <a href="{% url 'website:add_team' pk1=project.id %}" class="btn btn-success" role="button"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span>   Create a new team</a>
      </div>

Comment: that's a good thing to look at, but how does `app_name = 'website'`, at this **urls.py** level tell you he's doing namespaces?  Shouldn't that be checked on the main **urls.py**, with something like `url(....include("website.urls",namespace="website"))`

Comment: @JLPeyret this's a implicit convention: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#reversing-namespaced-urls.

Comment: ah, learned something new, txs.  I must have either missed it when I read the doc or else it's a newer addition - I only knew namespacing at the `include` level.  Nice use of conventions.

Comment: @Ben2pop Thanks for the update. Your urls look fine. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @dvnguyen thx for your answer, could you be a little bit clearer ? isn't it what I did with team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all() in my context ?

Comment: @Ben2pop: I've updated a clearer answer. Since you are using a object name `project`, you need set it to the context: `context['project'] = ...`

Comment: if I put context['project'] = project I get > project is not define if I put context['project'] = Project I get Reverse for 'team_select' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['website/project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$']

Comment: I edited my post to when the appeared .. without renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'project_details.html' it worked great

Comment: You shouldn't have to add `project` to the context. The [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name) should do this automatically since it has `model = Project`.